# Boost memory pools with dynamic parameters

Tags: c++, memory, boost

I know I can use boost [singleton_pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/singleton_pool.html) as follows:

```
 typedef boost::singleton_pool< OrderTag,sizeof(memSize)>Pool;
```

This is template class and memSize must be known in compile time.But I get memSize populated only during runtime and its value may vary  in different setups.Does that mean I can't use boost::pool classes at all in dynamic scenarios as all of them are template classes?

Comment: If you are storing a pool of objects, it is the size of that object. If you are storing a pool of pointers, then it is the size of the pointers.

Comment: Well,no, it a size for bytes block which is passed as param into the app and may vary...

Comment: what? I can't make any sense of what you said. Please provide a SSCE

Comment: Think of it this way:The memSize is a param which is loaded from XML in runtime.So it can never be predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [boost::pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.pool) interface and initialize the size on it's constructor :

```
void func()
{
  std::size_t memSize = getMemSize(); 
  boost::pool<> p(memSize);

  char* ptr = p.malloc();
}
```

Or use the the [boost::singleton_pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.singleton_pool) interface with a size of 1 and then allocate multiple chunks (you should definitely profile this solution BEFORE implementing it) :

```
typedef boost::singleton_pool<MyPoolTag, sizeof(char)> my_pool;
void func()
{
  std::size_t memSize = getMemSize(); 

  char * ptr = my_pool.ordered_malloc(memSize);

  my_pool::purge_memory();
}
```

Comment: I wish Boost could  document their  interfaces in such a way :)

Comment: The singleton way doesn't work.I mean it works but takes eternity to run a loop of allocations.Doing something like this:  demo_block *obj =(demo_block *) MyMemPool::ordered_malloc(sizeof(demo_block)); 
  obj->alpha = 100;
  obj->beta  = 200;
  obj->gama  = 300;

    MyMemPool::ordered_free(obj);

Comment: @MichaelIV nope, you have to synchronize the access to `boost::pool` yourself. And i expected such results for the second option :)